# Creating bot in Java or C# to a Flash based game

Tags: java, bots

First of all, im **not** looking for a bot, that's clicking on the screen so i can't use my computer.

I'm curios on how to interact with flash games without having to use awt.robot to click the screen.

Is this possible in Java, and how can i do it.

I prefer java, as that's what im best at, but if c# has some huge advantages im willing to use that :)

Answer (score 1):

> First of all, im not looking for a bot, that's clicking on the screen
>   so i can't use my computer.

You're mistaken if you think using AWT Robot clicking on the "screen" means you can't use your computer.

One way to do what you want by actually using Java's Robot would simply be to run another graphical display and have your bot act on that graphical display.

There are a **lot** of ways to do that.  A virtual machine would be one.  Spawning a second X server would be another (under Un*x most likely).  Configuring Windows so that it can accept several graphical logins at once and opening a "remote desktop" session, etc.

There are actually bots abusing Flash games and one way to do it is precisely by doing what I just described ; )

Comment: I'm pretty sure, that there is an easier/ more efficient way, to do it than spawning a second X server or a virtual machine. Imagine if i want my bot playing 100 games, at the same time. That would be very cpu intensive to run 100 virtual machines for that purpose :)

Comment: Furthermore, how would i go about spawning the second mouse i'd have to use to click buttons with ?

Comment: @Kevin: you don't "need" a second mouse.  Actually you don't even need to *display* the second screen.  The very fact that it exists is enough for you to do anything you want with the *Robot* class.  As for the perfs, no issue there: today's machines are very powerful.  You could create a hundred remote desktop in a single Windows machine (you need a licence to do that under Windows but with Linux it's free of course).  You could also have several browsers open in the same virtual machine...